# Caching data if connection is down

Tags: node.js, caching, ethereum, solidity

I've got a server that I'm relaying every action that I want to do with a smart contract, but let's say the server can't connect to the smart contract (the connection is down). How would I cache such actions and execute them once the connection is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interaction with smart contract (SC) has 2 types:

- Call to update status (write data)
- Call to view function (read data)

In order to do the write data, we need:

- SC address
- Method name
- Data option
- Parameters
- Sender

So we can organize into a JS object

```
{
 'address': 0x..,
 'method': 'transfer',
 'dataOption': { 
    'from': '0x...',
    'value': 100 (wei)
  },
 'params': ['param1', 'param2', ...]
}
```

Then you can determine where should we use it depends on the use cases:

- Can be store at server using: SQL, MongoDB, json file...
- Can be store inside the front-end using: storage

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about smart contracts and the blockchain, but it sounds like you need some kind of persistent data store. Like a relational database. Perhaps you could use something like [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) and some kind of task scheduler, such as [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron), to query for and execute the cached actions every so often.

As I said, I know next to nothing about smart contracts, so maybe this kind of caching is contradicting the decentralization principles of the blockchain and such.

**Edit:**
If the volume is low enough you may simply be able to cache in-memory using a `Map` or `Object`, and then still probably use some kind of task scheduling utility.